# Как получить необходимое значение из комбинированного массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте.

Есть комбинированный массив `$c = array_combine($a, $b);`

Как извлечь необходимое значение из **$c**, указав ключ, где
`$c=array_combine(key=>значение)`?

P.S. Это нужно в примере ниже:
`if ($_POST['age']==1) {$scoring_age=Значение указанного ключа";}`

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как этот PHP-код относится к SQL?

Comment: исправил, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c["green"]);
```

Вывод

```
avocado
```

Comment: получилось, спасибо)